# Desplegar Imagen sobre una misma ventana con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

como describo en el titulo lo que intento hacer es que al hacer click sobre el icono de una imagen o bien un boton pueda desplegarla sobre la misma pantalla, justo como en gmail se hace al abrir un png o jpg y que al dar click se cierra esta.

No tengo mucha idea si se hace con javascript ni como se hace por eso pido ayudo si alguien tiene la experiencia y conoce una manera sencilla sobre esto.

de antemano muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas es [Lightbox](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). Es la manera mas sencilla de hacerlo, pues solo necesitas agregar `data-lightbox="TITULO"` a una etiqueta `<a>`dentro de la cual puedes poner tu imagen

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Clicke la imagen
<a href="https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6v66lJ5K61r0taux.jpg" data-lightbox="smile">  <img height="42" width="42" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6v66lJ5K61r0taux.jpg"> </a>
```

Comment: Así es, es exactamente lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te sirva y si es lo que necesitabas te agradecería marcarlo como respuesta. :)